# Help identifying pneumatically activated switch with possible BMS

Tags: switches, identification, pressure, bms

Some decent googling has yielded me no results.

Attached are pictures of a component that allows power from a 3-5v power supply to flow when positive pressure is applied to one side or negative pressure on the opposing side. It also has a voltage cutoff. The internal diode has the text "C912 AYCeY".

I am also interested in figuring out how the sensor (unidirectionally!) detects the pressure difference.

Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By the look of it, it could be an electret pressure switch.

An electret microphone would serve as a differential pressure sensor if the opposite sides of the electret could be isolated.

Answer (score 0):

C912 is an "SMD Code" used by some Mfg. instead of full P/N
The bottom row AYCeY are traceability & date codes just used by Mfg/Dist.
Case size appears to be sot235 aka 5-SOT-23 or others...
Due to a lack of passive parts, it is probably just a BJT transistor used as a switch.

Just a quick guess is that compression causes a black deposit of carbon to make contact with the metallic disk and suitable spacer.